# Data not written correctly to MySQL 5 database from a classic ASP website

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I'm in the midst of changing from an ACCESS database to a MYSQL 5 database for a client of mine. Their website is entirely coded in classic ASP.

I used a tool (Navicat for MySQL) to import all tables and data from access to MySQL. Seems to have worked really well.

I'm now trying to test the website and the administration functions which they use to manage their product data (which is stored in the db).

When editing a product in the ASP admin section, they can update prices, descriptions, etc.

Functionally, it works. But for two problems:

1) When updating the price in the asp form and submitting it, the value in the database is wrong. (i.e. I enter $1189 and the value in the database becomes 11890000.00). There is always four zeros added to the number I enter. The datatype in the database is Decimal 19,4 - which as far as I can tell the recommended datatype for currency.

2) Within the asp form, we can also update the description of the product. However, when submitted to the database any description I enter becomes something like: "tâ€¹" (jibberish, basically). I assumed this was related to the character sets maybe being incorrect, but as far as I can tell they are OK. The database uses the default latin1 -- cp1252 and the webpage/application is using iso-8859-1 (which I believe is the same). What is also strange is it is ONLY the description that is a problem. The datatype of the description is LONGTEXT. All other values (like the product name) are updated and stored to the database properly (product name, for example, is a varchar).

I've been trying to google these problems to find the answer and am very surprised to have not had any luck. I'm new to MySQL so if the answer is an obvious one, i'm sorry!

Here, hopefully, is the code where records are written to the db:

```
Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload.1")
Upload.OverwriteFiles = true
Upload.SetMaxSize 2048576   ' Limit files to 1MB
Upload.Save session("rootpath")&"\public\graphics\uploads\"

dim rst, oc, pid
pid = Upload.Form("pid")
set rst = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM Trailers WHERE Trailer_ID="&pid, connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

rst("Trailer_Description") = Upload.Form("description")
rst("Trailer_Price") = Upload.Form("price")
rst.Update
```

Note: "Upload.Form" is used instead of request.form because images are uploaded within this form using an ASP.Upload component - creating the upload object. I've taken everything else in an effort to isolate the problem...

Thanks,

Comment: This is two separate questions and is very hard to answer with zero lines of code posted.

Comment: @tadman I thought their was a possibility of the issues being related so I lumped it all together. And wasn't sure if the problem could be code related, or the datatype, or the character set, etc. so didn't know what all to include. Was hoping someone would have a theory...

Comment: You'll need to post the code where you insert records into the database. You're probably converting something wrong, or your character encoding is not set correctly. These issues are not necessarily related.

Comment: Ok @tadman -- I added a code sample. It seems like such a simple thing i'm trying to do its got me pulling my hair out. Thank you for your help in advance...

Comment: What would be better is the code where you perform the `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

If the application has a database creation script, you're probably better off using it to create the tables etc. and then port the data from Access to MySQL.

I've not worked with Navicat, so I can't speak to how well it does/doesn't work - but in another project I work on, migrating from Access to MySQL has always been problematic at best unless you let the program create the tables, indexes, defaults, etc. and then just move the data as a separate step.